# Foundation: background image outside container

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am working on a clients project at the moment but I'm stuck at a crucial part. How can I get the image to be outside the container without losing any responsiveness?

This is what I need:
[wireframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSBbI.jpg)

I tried to Google this, came across this codepen solution: Paulie-D/pen/bALoz

but somehow I can't get that to work. This is my code:
http://codepaste.net/imfthu

Comment: we need HTML and CSS and maybe use fiddle.com

Comment: Please explain what "didn't work" means.

Comment: That's one of mine....:) Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does this help - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yOjKQP

Comment: Thanks Paulie, this came quite close but I couldn't fix it yet. I really tried making a codepen or stackoverflow code (with foundation), but couldnt get it right. So here's the link of the project: http://www.iturl.nl/snALwk9

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for? I used `overflow:hidden` on `body` and added your bg image `before` the right column + added the same `padding` as your image `height` to the right column
http://codepen.io/anceque/pen/yOjjOE